# return statement in c++

Tags: c++

What means

> failing to provide a return after a loop that contains a return is an error

in "*C++ primer fifth*", page 295?

Especially, the compiler does not detect this error, what happens at run time is undefined.

I use the book sample like: (vs2013)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using std::string;

bool str_subrange(const string &str1, const string&str2) {
    if (str1.size() == str2.size())
        return str1 == str2;
    auto size = (str1.size() < str2.size()) ? str1.size() : str2.size();
    for (decltype(size)i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        if (str1[i] != str2[i])
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    if (str_subrange("lyc", "talent"))
        std::cout << "yes" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "nope" << std::endl;;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It works well, I want to know which situations that "return" is must.

Comment: Try calling `str_subrange("", "anything")`.

Comment: Note that your function compares only `str[0]` with `str[1]` - in first iteration it returns.

Answer (score 4):

If `size` is 0, the for loop never executes and so the method has no return value.

Answer (score 2):

If `size` ends up as 0 (e.g. one of the strings is ""), your loop is never run.  If the loop never runs, then what is returned is undefined, because the program won't write a result to be returned to the caller of the function. The result you get is whatever was preexisting in the memory contents of where the return value is expected on the stack.

When you decide to return values inside loops, or other grouping statements (e.g. "if"), always manually run your code in your head checking to ensure you return a value on every valid path and even if loops don't run.

Comment: "The result you get is whatever was preexisting in the memory contents of where the return value is expected on the stack." - This is not strictly true. For example, [here](http://goo.gl/W7IMWo) `bar` always returns 1 even when it picks the branch that uses the return non-value from `foo`. There's also no need to keep track of missing return values manually if you compile with warnings.

Comment: @chris, cool website, but sorry my assembly isn't the best. G++ looks like it can jump out of foo without setting a return value, though bar always returns the same thing. Is that what you are getting at? Clang 3.4.1 looks more forgiving (and gives a warning) and always gives 1 for both examples.

Comment: Yeah, `foo` is what it looks like - return 1 if the given value is not 0 and just return with no value specified if the given value is 0. But then things get more interesting with `bar`. If it calls `foo(0)`, the compiler knows this is undefined behaviour and thus that branch can never be taken. Rather than return whatever garbage was sitting there, the compiler assumes that branch cannot be taken and always chooses the other branch, which just returns 1. Aside from that, GCC for sure gives that warning with `-Wall`.

Comment: Your point about Clang is great, too. Rather than needing to go through `bar`, we can just look at `foo`. Rather than return whatever garbage was there in some cases and 1 in other cases, it always returns 1.

Comment: @chris, really cool, how did you learn that and how do I learn more about stuff like that? I've played with Clang/LLVM and am reading the Dragon book, but I'm not really sure where else to go.

Comment: Any assembly I picked up was just from hanging around on SO before I actually started learning ARM in class. Just what can happen with neat undefined behaviour optimizations came up with [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx).

Comment: You shouldn't try to reason about how undefined behaviour will manifest ala *"what is returned is undefined"* (the function might not even return), or "result you get is whatever was preexisting in the memory contents of where the return value is expected on the stack" (again, anything may happen, but even if it returns the return value may be expected in a register, or the place to which it returns may be wrong, or the other stack or register content may be corrupt).  You can't expect proper flow of execution.

Comment: We were discussion varying compiler implementations since undefined is left up to the compiler and behavior is not guaranteed. You should never depend on a specific behavior a certain compiler produces for something which is "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

In such case where using loops, if conditions, always return from end of function, assign a return value at start and update that value based on conditions.